# PHP traverse a string and line break at certain substring

Tags: php, string, traversal, stripos

If I have this one long string:

```
WAITLIST, 91630, ACCY 2001 , 10, Intro Financial Accounting, 3.00, Zou, Y, DUQUES 251,     TR09:35AM   - 10:50AM, 01/13/14   - 04/28/14 , , WAITLIST, 90003, ACCY 2001 , 11, Intro Financial Accounting, 3.00, Zou, Y, DUQUES 254, TR11:10AM - 12:25PM, 01/13/14 - 04/28/14 , , OPEN, 91212, ACCY 2001 , 12, Intro Financial Accounting, 3.00, Zou, Y, 1957 E B12, TR02:20PM - 03:35PM, 01/13/14 - 04/28/14 , , WAITLIST, 90004, ACCY 2002 , 10, Intro Managerial Accounting, 3.00, Linsley, C, FNGR 222, TR11:10AM - 12:25PM, 01/13/14 - 04/28/14 , ,
```

I want to search for ", ," and add a line break directly after each occurrence so my long string looks like this:

```
WAITLIST 91630 ACCY 2001 10 Intro Financial Accounting 3.00 Zou, Y DUQUES 251 TR09:35AM - 10:50AM 01/13/14 - 04/28/14
WAITLIST 90003 ACCY 2001 11 Intro Financial Accounting 3.00 Zou, Y DUQUES 254 TR11:10AM - 12:25PM 01/13/14 - 04/28/14 
OPEN 91212 ACCY 2001 12 Intro Financial Accounting 3.00 Zou, Y 1957 E B12 TR02:20PM - 03:35PM 01/13/14 - 04/28/14 

ETC....
```

I was thinking I could use stripos to record the positions of each ", ," and add it to an array. Then I could use a for loop to traverse through the array and append a '<br>' after the positions of each double comma. Would that work? Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried `explode(", ,", $str);` ? Or `str_replace(", ,", ",,<br>", $str);`

Comment: Why don't you try it and post the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
$str = 'WAITLIST, 91630, ACCY 2001 , 10, Intro Financial Accounting, 3.00, Zou, Y, DUQUES 251,     TR09:35AM   - 10:50AM, 01/13/14   - 04/28/14 , , WAITLIST, 90003, ACCY 2001 , 11, Intro Financial Accounting, 3.00, Zou, Y, DUQUES 254, TR11:10AM - 12:25PM, 01/13/14 - 04/28/14 , , OPEN, 91212, ACCY 2001 , 12, Intro Financial Accounting, 3.00, Zou, Y, 1957 E B12, TR02:20PM - 03:35PM, 01/13/14 - 04/28/14 , , WAITLIST, 90004, ACCY 2002 , 10, Intro Managerial Accounting, 3.00, Linsley, C, FNGR 222, TR11:10AM - 12:25PM, 01/13/14 - 04/28/14 , ,';
$val = str_replace(', ,', '<br />', $str);
echo $val;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the string with `<br>` using [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/str_replace):

```
$result = str_replace(", ,", "<br>", $str);
```